# Assign user from profile id when certain condition matches

Tags: trigger, profile

I have a criteria where i need to select and assign user from particular profile when an 'if' condition matches in a trigger.
Issue is the profile contains lots of users. I can select any user randomly from the profile for my requirement. Can this be done using trigger?

Comment: Does it actually need to be a random user with a specific profile, or could you take them in sequence based on the CreateDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using using [SOQL OFFSET](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm) based on [How do I request a single random row from a force.com database in SOQL? by @metadaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302018/54026).

```
Id profileId = // Some Profile Id that you want a random user from.
Integer count = [SELECT COUNT() FROM User where ProfileId = :profileId];
// Limit the count to 2000 due to maximum offset restriction.
count = Math.min(2000, count);
Integer rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count).intValue();
User u = [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT 1 OFFSET :rand];
System.debug(u.Id);
```

Note that this is restricted to 2000 Users with the same profile due to the maximum offset of 2,000 rows.